# Reaching a Microsoft SQL Server 2017 cluster from another device

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Let say I have a python service in one instance. This service needs to reach a MSSQL cluster of 5 nodes that is in an other location, with different IP addresses. Cluster creds:
user: my_user
password: my_password
Database: my_database

What is the IP address that I should provide to my python code so that it can reach this cluster? Indeed, there are many different IP addresses in this cluster (one for each node).

In many storage engines, there are the notions of master/primary and slave/secondary, but I don't know much more, especially for Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the MSSQL cluster is setup on windows, it will have a virtual IP address which is different than the IP addresses assigned to each node. This virtual IP address will always point to the active node. The application can connect to the SQL server using this virtual IP address.

Comment: So all important IP adress are: IP adress addressed to each node + this virtual IP address?